# What is the first javascript file that gets run in ember.js app? (in the browser)

Tags: ember.js

What the very first javascript file that ember looks to run *in the browser*? I need to access localStorage, so am looking for a file that is actually part of the app js, config/env won't do.

Bonus points: Is this different for apps using Module Unification? I am (unfortunately) using ember 2.13. If you know which file people *most typically* put their earliest app initialization stuff in, that would be pretty helpful too.

Background info: I need to modify some settings that are defined in environment.js, but I need to read localStorage to determine what settings to apply. Thus, I cannot do this in the actual environment.js file itself. I happen to be using this for a sort of a hack, but it's more of a testing/debugging/developer/inspection utility function that will be used in production from the browser console.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Could you provide more specific use-case?

Comment: I don't know what other info you want, can you be more specific in your answer?

Comment: Perhaps you missed the "Background info:"?

Comment: Setting defined in `environment.js` can't be changed in runtime and used by ember-cli to build app. You can only read them when application is running in browser. And background info does not specify what settings you are talking about. Do you want to change setting related to some ember addon? Or settings that you read and use in your code? In second case it's easy to help - you need to create a service `settings` and it will be able to access both settings defined in `environment.js` and `localStorage` and then merge them. In case of addons it usually harder and depends on addon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [ember-patch-config](https://github.com/ramybenaroya/ember-patch-config). It is a small npm package I wrote for patching/modifying configuration properties at runtime before the app script is even loaded.

**Install**

`npm install ember-patch-config --save-dev`

**Usage**

First you need to import `EmberApp` from a different location. No worries, it extends the original `EmberApp` which installed in `node_modules`:

```js
// ember-cli-build.js

const EmberApp = require('ember-patch-config/ember-app');

module.exports = function (defaults) {
    const app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then, add an inline script in `app/index.html` (before the app & vendor scripts):

```html
<!-- app/index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
{{content-for 'rev-header'}}
<html>
  <!-- ... -->
  <body>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script>
        window.configToPatch = {
            property1: 'value1',
            property2: 'value2',
            property3: {
                someKey: 'someValue'
            },
            property4: localStorage.getItem('property4')
        };
    </script>
    <!-- ... -->
  </body>
</html>
```

The content of `window.configToPatch` will be **DEEPLY MERGED** into the module `<your-app-name>/config/environment.js` at runtime, before the app is initialized (even before initializers).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried initializers? You can read about them at https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.1.0/applications/initializers/.

Comment: would it actually just be app.js?

Comment: I ended up just putting my changes in app.js